# Use html link to open javascript modal

Tags: javascript

I want to open a modal each time I click a HTML link. In my navigation bar I have a link called "rules" where all the websites rules are written. Everytime someone click the link I want it to open a javascript modal. With low javascript knowledge I'm personally not able to create something as simple as that without problems.

Heres the modal script and HTML:

```
<div class="modal-background">
<form action="/etc/set_cookie.php" method="post">
  <div id="modal">
    <div class="modalconent tabs">
        <fieldset>
        <span class="close">×</span>
          <h2 class="fs-title">Cookies</h2>
          <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We use cookies to improve your experience</h3>
             <iframe style="width:100%; height:80px;" src="/etc/txt/cookies.php" ></iframe><br />
           <input type="submit" name="cookie" value="Accept" id="button" class="btn fr" style="width:180px; padding:10px;" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>


<script>
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "none"
    };
};

$(".modal-background, .modal-close").on("click", function(){
  $(".modal-container, .modal-background").hide();
});


// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

What I want is have the link call open the script that are located in a different folder, each time its pressed. All I've seen online is buttons with this function but since I'm not good with javascript I'm not able to rewrite it to work with my modal script.

Comment: I noticed I shared wrong html code, but the everything is the same without this beeing the one i use for cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general Modal infotmation you get this from http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

```
// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

However if you are using Jquery (and from your code you are) then you have something easier to do:
Now what you can do is assign an ID to your link and do this:

```
 $("#YourIDHereLink").on("click", function ()
    {
        $("#Modal").css("display", "block");  
}
```

Where if you want to hide it replace block with "none"

Generally I recommend the 2nd approach

Comment: same problem as the answer above, the modal load right away and the functions to hide the modal dont work

Comment: did you try the code below? Try to replace it with "none" instead of "block"

Answer (score 0):

To call a javascript function using a link, simply do it like this:

```
<a href="javascript:yourfunction();">Link to Javascript function</a>
```

Just make sure the file your javascript function is in, is linked in the head of the html.

Comment: Then I just give the script a `function yourfunction() { the rest of the code }`?

Comment: I tried doing this now but it seems like the modal load on refresh and neither of the closing methods worked

Comment: could you make a jsfiddle of your problem? would make things a lot easier.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bkbox4md/ as i wrote in the hmtl, we are talking about 2 pages. one with the nav bar where i got the link and a second with the script and the modal html

Answer (score 0):

[ModaliseJS](https://github.com/AlexisTM/modalise.js), can do the trick.

HTML : I just added a "confirm" class and some JS.

ModaliseJS will close the modal when you click on any element in the modal with the classes `.close`, `.confirm`, `.cancel`, firing events `onShow`, `onHide`, `onCancel`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <title>Modal example</title>
  <script src="js/modalise.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Example modal 1</h1>
  <button id="openModal">Show the modal</button>
  <div class="modal-background">
    <form action="/etc/set_cookie.php" method="post">
      <div id="modal">
        <div class="modalconent tabs">
          <fieldset>
            <span class="close">×</span>
            <h2 class="fs-title">Cookies</h2>
            <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We use cookies to improve your experience</h3>
            <iframe style="width:100%; height:80px;" src="/etc/txt/cookies.php"></iframe>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="cookie" value="Accept" id="button" class="btn fr confirm" style="width:180px; padding:10px;" />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myModal = {}

    window.onload = function() {
      // It is one of the button Modalise will attach the Show event.
      // Note that you can use Modalise without the events, by omitting the .attach() function.
      // Then, you can use show() or hide() to use it manually without overload. 
      var btnOpen = document.getElementById('openModal');

      // Modalise(id, options);
      myModal = new Modalise('exampleModal', {
          btnsOpen: [btnOpen]
        })
        .attach()
        .on('onShow', console.log)
        .on('onConfirm', console.log)
        .on('onHide', console.log);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```